# Exponential distribution probability independent events

Tags: probability

The lifetime of a mechanical component has an exponential distribution with an expected life of $6$ months. Let $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ represent the lifetimes of three such components. If these components are independent of each other, what is the probability that all have failed within one year?

I get some of the following:

$$E(T) = 0.5 \text{ years}$$

$$\lambda = 2$$

$$\begin{align*}
Pr(T<<t) 
&= 1 - Pr(T>t)\\\\
&= 1 - e^{-2}\\\\
&= 0.86466\\\\
\end{align*}$$

After that I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got that part right. For each individual component, we have a mean lifetime $T$ of $6$ months so $T\sim \exp\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)$

$$P(T\lt 12)=\int_0^{12} \frac{1}{6}e^{-\frac{t}{6}}dt=1-\exp(-2)$$

By independence the probability that all three fail is

$$\left(1-\exp(-2)\right)^3$$

Comment: Thanks that matches up to an answer i have.

Answer (score 0):

If there are independent just multiply the probability so, $(0.86466)^3 = 0.646451735442696$ is the probability of all the 3 fail after a year.